Unity Animation Rigging Override Transform is not affecting rotation on startup
Given: I have animation of character arming the pistol using IK.
The pistol In Character's Idle State is on the characters hip and it's barrel is looking at the floor.


Next I have armed state when character holds the gun in front of him

Now I want to change rotation of the gun as I want it too look upwards.
I have rig layer for armed pose. RigLayer_WeaponArmed is responsible for armed IK.
It has one child object WeaponPose.
WeaponPose has 2 components
1.Multi-Position Constraint
2.Override Transform

The problem: During inplay I can modify the rotation of the pistol and achieve desired rotation.But when I copy transform that I found was correct for me, stop the game, paste it's values into the WeaponPose and launch the game again than this change is completely ignored and pistol rotation is the same as before, it is still looking at the floor.


I feel based on the second screenshot this is an error with the Multi-Position constraint. It's been a few days since you created this, any luck?

Hello @Chad, I was able to fix it using Override Transfrom component and not giving source for constrained object, just fill constrained object field.
Still don't know why is it so.
